# Archival lists of most subscribed YouTube accounts?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to find the top X YouTube accounts by subscriber count for Y year---say, the top 100 accounts in 2015? I don't see anything in the API docs, and while there are services like [SocialBlade](https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/500/mostsubscribed) and [VidStatsX](https://vidstatsx.com/youtube-top-1000-most-subscribed-channels), they don't provide archived lists, and the data is not captured on archive.org.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Analytics API doesn't provide this functionality. You can get data about views, likes, and dislikes, but you must provide one or more channel IDs.

> Required Parameters: **ids**
>
> Identifies the YouTube channel or content owner for which you are
> retrieving YouTube Analytics data.
>
> - To request data for a YouTube
>   channel, set the ids parameter value to either channel==MINE or
>   channel==CHANNEL_ID, where CHANNEL_ID identifies the currently
>   authenticated user's YouTube channel.
> - To request data for a YouTube
>   CMS content owner, set the ids parameter value to
>   contentOwner==OWNER_NAME, where OWNER_NAME is the CMS user ID for the
>   user.

Use the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) section on the reference page to test the possibilities.